# Is the product of two numbers both less than one less than one

Tags: fractions

I'm bad at mathematics, and I wanted to know something.

Say there are two numbers $a$ and $b$ where $a, b \in \Bbb R$ $-1 < a < 1$ and $-1 < b < 1$
Is it necessary that $a \times b < 1$?

**Edit:** I was in hurry and didn't notice the big mistake I did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because $|ab|=|a||b|<1\cdot 1 = 1$, hence $-1<ab<1$.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily:
$$
(-2)\times(-2)=4.
$$
It will be true if the two numbers are positive and less than one.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but I think he meant positive reals.  But your answer is correct based on what he supplied.

Comment: I read $-1<a<1$ and $-1<b<1$ in the question (probably updated in the grace period, so the edit is not visible in history).